# Rails4 client side validation not working for registrations edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, devise

I have used rails4_client_side_validation in my application. I am unable to do client side validation in edit form for registration of devise. This gem is working good with forms of other modules.

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, validate: true, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, class: 'global-form' }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

I have included validate: true Besides i also tried with validate: true option in the form field also.

```
<div class='row'><%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i>
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off", :validate => true %></div>
```

I get only server side validation error message as current password required but unable to get client side validation error.

Answer (score 0):

Fror HTML5 client side validations no need to use `validate: true`, Use this instead

```
<%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off", :required => true %></div>
```

Comment: Its one of the solution but html5 is not supported by all the browsers and versions of browsers. Rails 4 client side validation is dynamic and has been working perfectly with other forms except forms of devise.

Comment: then you need to validate with javascript

Comment: yes RSB i am thinking of writing my own validation script for it.